# How do I set up a counter that will not reset when program restarts?

Tags: c++

all. I'm new to programming and I'm only in my second semester at school. I've learned a lot but the programs in the curriculum are very basic. I'm trying to challenge myself a little more. I'd like to create a program with a counter that is saved through multiple uses. I know it must be something basic but I can't find it online.

How would I set this up? What #include statement should I use for this if any? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What operating system/environment?  On Mac OS X you could save to the [defaults system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defaults_(software)), for example.

Answer (score 5):

Write it into a file and read it out again when the program starts the second time.

To do this, you can either read up on [C++ File IO](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) or use the C family of file IO tools including [`fopen`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/), `fwrite`, and `fread`.

Other forms of persistent store include databases and nonvolatile memory (if those are available to you).

Comment: or put it into nonvolatile memory, if you can.

Comment: @user1095108, True, if you have that available.

Comment: Thank you, Merlin and Dub. I'll try it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @prgmmngBlues, I added a couple of links to point you in the right direction.

Comment: What if you have multiple copies of the program running?

Comment: @KevinZ, Then you lock the file before trying to read it or write to it. But if you wanted true synchronization, then you would maintain the counter from `0` in each instance of the program, and on program exit, take the file lock, read the value, and your value to it, and write it out again.

Comment: Thanks again, Merlin. The link is appreciated

Comment: @KevinZ, It depends on what your requirements are when multiple instances are running. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows, you could write the value to the registry.  Then read the value when the program starts each time.